# How can I calculate difference between dates in the same column but different categories?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I'm sure someone will point out that this is a basic reshaping problem, but I guess I'm poor at Googling, so I'm offering my question up to the gods of Stack Overflow.

My problem is that I want to calculate the number of days between two dates (of Rank 1 and 2) that come from the same column but have different values in another column (Rank). Here's an example of the dataset schema:

```
User   Date        Rank
Bob    2016-12-01    3
Bob    2016-12-07    2
Bob    2016-12-10    1
```

What I would like is this:

```
User   Date1        Date2        DaysBetween
Bob    2016-12-07   2016-12-10        3
```

Ideally, I wanted to do this in Tableau, but SQL/BigQuery is OK, too.

Comment: Does a user ever have more than one row with the same rank? Are you ignoring rank 3 altogether? Or do you also want the days between rank 3 and 2? In you example, the rank appears to be just the reverse order of the date. Is that always the case?

Comment: For a Tableau solution, I would probable use a table calc. Depending on the answers to the above questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 'Bob' AS User, DATE '2016-12-01' AS Date, 3 AS Rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob' AS User, DATE '2016-12-07' AS Date, 2 AS Rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob' AS User, DATE '2016-12-10' AS Date, 1 AS Rank 
)
SELECT 
  User, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 2 THEN Date END) AS Date1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 1 THEN Date END) AS Date2,
  DATE_DIFF(MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 1 THEN Date END), 
            MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 2 THEN Date END), DAY) AS DaysBetween
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY User
```

Note  - this is in BigQuery [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 'Bob' AS User, DATE '2016-12-01' AS Date, 3 AS Rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob' AS User, DATE '2016-12-07' AS Date, 2 AS Rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob' AS User, DATE '2016-12-10' AS Date, 1 AS Rank 
)
SELECT 
  User, Date1, Date2, 
  DATE_DIFF(Date2, Date1, DAY) AS DaysBetween
FROM (
  SELECT 
    User, Rank, Date as Date2, 
    LEAD(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Date1
  FROM YourTable
)
WHERE Rank = 1
```